# Why is my subroutine not updating the current date and time as I expect?

Tags: excel, vba

My *Workbook_SheetChange* code seems to not be running.

I have tried changing it several different ways, including Setting objects and not Setting objects. No change event seems to trigger.

My current code is below, but I have completely scratched other versions that don't even reference sheet names. None of them seem to work. I have another wb with a Worksheet Change code that works.

I am expecting my summary sheet date and time cell - Worksheets("GL 1500").("B2") - to update with the current date and time any time anything in the range "C31:P46" on the summary tab, or the alternate range on any other tab, changes, but it has not updated with any changes I make to any worksheet.

What stupid mistake am I making?

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Sh.Name = "GL 1500" Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("c31:p46")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            With Worksheets("GL 1500")
                .Range("b2").Value = Now
            End With
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If

    Else
        If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("e14:k39")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            With Worksheets("GL 1500")
                .Range("b2").Value = Now
            End With
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your code in the `ThisWorkbook` module?  Did you try adding a breakpoint to see if your code is even running?

Comment: Make sure you events did not get turned off by accident.

Comment: Added the breakpoint, and it does not trigger when I make a change. So what did I do to turn off events? The first time I ran my original code, it ran and there was an object error. Since that time, nothing.

Comment: It turned off the events, then your code errored and the line to turn the events back on never ran.  So the events are off.

Comment: type `Application.enableevents=true` in the immediate window and hit enter.

Comment: Done. And it works. Thanks! Now how do I flag comments as useful? lol